# Using Elsa Workflow, how can I inherit CorrelationId in sub workflow using IWorkflowBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, workflow, elsa-workflows, x-correlation-id

Ciao,

I'm writing some workflows using Elsa Workflow .NET library. I'm using last stable version (v. 2.10.2.2).

I've wrote two workflows:

```
public class MyWorkflow : IWorkflow
{
    public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.WorkflowBuilder
            .HttpEndpoint(setup => setup.WithPath("myworkflow"))
            .RunWorkflow<OtherWorkflow>(RunWorkflowMode.Blocking)
            .Finish();
    }
}

public class OtherWorkflow : IWorkflow
{
    public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.WorkflowBuilder
            .HttpEndpoint(setup => setup.WithPath("otherworkflow"))
            .Finish();
    }
}
```

And I've create a new instance of **MyWorkflow** with this HTTP request:

```
curl --location 'https://localhost:7236/myworkflow' \
--header 'X-Correlation-Id: document1.docx'
```

The sub-workflow **OtherWorkflow** has a new CorrelationId, like picture below:

[image: Workflow picture]

I need that all sub-workflows inherit CorrelationId of parent, because I will have a lot of sub-workflows that needs to be correlated with it's parent.

How can I reach my goal programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone is still looking an answer for this, it can be done by providing `correlationId` as the value in `Correlation Id` field in `Advanced` tab of `RunWorkflow` activity.

[image: Reference Screenshot]